# Java - xgboost DMatrix input

Tags: java, xgboost

When creating a DMatrix in java with the xgboost4j package, at first i succeed to create the matrix using a "filepath".

```
DMatrix trainMat = new DMatrix("...\\xgb_training_input.csv");
```

But when I try to train the model:

```
Booster booster = XGBoost.train(trainMat, params, round, watches, null, null);
```

I get the following error:

```
...regression_obj.cc:108: label must be in [0,1] for logistic regression
```

now my data is solid. I've checked it out on an xgb model built in python.
I'm guessing the problem is with the data format somehow.
currently the format is as follows:

```
x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y
```

where x1-x5 are "Real" numbers and y is either 0 or 1. file end is .csv

Maybe the separator shouldn't be ',' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DMatrix gets an .libsvm file. which can be easily created with python.

libsvm looks like this:

`target 0:column1 1:column2 2:column3` ... and so on

so the target is the first column, while every other column (predictor) is being attached to increasing index with ":" in between.

Comment: Come to think of it, this way of saving data will work great with sparse data. If a data value is NA or 0 for that column (the increasing index) you simply don't write it.

Comment: Do you have this function to convert text to libsvm for dummies?

Comment: If the text is in the format I've mentioned above, its already a .libsvm formatted. If it doesn't, it has to have a certain structure. Simply "text" wont cut it.